# change background color of a select box if user has made a selection

Tags: jquery, select

I have several select boxes that i use to filter my datatable. All the boxes have their unique id's, all the boxes share same class. For better usability i would like to highlight the select box by changing the backgorund color if user has made a selection and thus filter is active.

What would be the best way approach this by using jquery.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What did you try so far, and how did the results differ from what you expected?

Comment: I did try to add a class, tried .css() but i can't get my head around how to know if a selection is made and if it is, in which box and after that if the user resets the filter manually by selecting the initial first value again i would need to change the appearence of the select box back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('select').change(function() {
  $(this).addClass('addclass')

})
```

```css
.addclass {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

You can add a class when a selection is done. On that class you can set the background color

Comment: I can get the above to work, but only when using the select boxes #id. And eventhough its working, i would still need a way to remove the class if user  resets the filter by selecting back the first option.